# PHP Need Help In Sub Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a two table 1. grocery_product and 2. grocery_attribute where i can get all data from grocery_product my array look like as below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [pname] => Royal Moong Dal/Moong Dal
        [categoryid] => 4
        [subcatid] => 3
        [added_date] => 2016-08-16
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [pname] => Royal Toor Dal/Arhar Dal/Tuver Dal
        [categoryid] => 4
        [subcatid] => 3
        [added_date] => 2016-08-16
    )

)
```

What i want to do that in my grocerry_attribute table i am passing grocery_product_id and fetch all data from grocery_attribute where product is only one and attributes are multiple.
My grocery atrtribute table look like  .

```
id                      1
product_id              2
price                   1500
discount                15
product_qty             20

id                      2
product_id              2
price                   1000
discount                10
product_qty             50
```

i want to fetch one grocery_product(id=1) and its attribute data.
Query ??

Comment: Are you looking for MySQL query?

Comment: you have a 1 to Many relation. So you should use 2 queries, 1 to get the product and then another to get the attributes for that product. using JOINs in this case will return rows with redundant data, unless you want statistical data(counts or comma separated values), then that is what you should go for.

Comment: I am getting all attribute.but when i passed the product_id(1) and get attribute data(4 row) my array is 0 to 3.. i want to get one array and all its attribute on one array.> how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` like,

```
SELECT p.id,p.pname,g.price,g.discount,g.product_qty FROM 
   grocery_product as p
   LEFT JOIN grocery_attribute as g
   ON p.id = g.product_id
   WHERE p.id=2
```

Now you can loop for attributes and show different `price`, `discount`, and `product_qty` for a single product.

```
// Let $products is multidimensional array
if(!empty($products) && isset($products[0]['pname'])){
    echo '<h1>'.$products[0]['pname'].'</h1>';
    foreach($products as $product){
        echo 'Price:'.$product['price']."\n";
        echo 'Discount:'.$product['discount']."\n";
        echo 'Product Quantity:'.$product['product_qty']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting all attribute.but when i passed the product_id(1) and get attribute data(4 row) my array is 0 to 3.. i want to get one array and all its attribute on one array.> how it is possible?

Comment: it is possible to group by product_id ?

Comment: If you have multiple attributes and want to show all then don't use `GROUP BY` and if you want to show the `product_id=2` and whose `attribute_id =1` then append `AND g.id=1` in your query it will give a single record.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge..but am looking for one product array & in product array all its attribute array ...it is possible ?